# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSURLRequest *'

Tags: xcode4.3

Hello every one this is my simple code.. what i am missing ? it is two days i am trying to sort out the problem.. any idea?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dog" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURL *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];  <<<<<< HERE WHERE THE ERROR COME OUT <<<<<<
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadRequest` argument is of type `NSURLRequest` and not `NSURL` as in your case. 
And are you sure this line is compiling ?? :

```
NSURL *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

As far as I know the method returns object of type NSURLRequest and not NSURL

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. The app is working without problem, just I've got this warning from Xcode and i would like to fix it..

Comment: NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  This is the right code. Just miss a little part and i was not able to see.

Comment: Well, that was wrote in the answer :)